# Iterate over inputs with same name and id

Tags: jquery

I have those inputs in a table:

```
<tr><td><input type="hidden" id="layer_pk" name="layer_pk"  value="1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" id="layer_pk" name="layer_pk"  value="2" /></td></tr>
```

and I would like to put those input values into a list when a button to move up/down the table rows is hitten

I dont understand why this code put only the selected row input value, not all rows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".up,.down").click(function(){
          var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
          if ($(this).is(".up")) {
              row.insertBefore(row.prev());
          } else {
              row.insertAfter(row.next());
          }
          var checks = new Array();
          $("#layer_pk").each(function(idx, elem) {
              checks.push($(elem).val());
          });
          alert(checks);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Don't reuse the same ID for more than one element, this is illegal and  will make many things fail.

Comment: `$(this)`refers to only the one clicked element not all the `.up, .down` elements

Comment: As an alternative to using an id in this case, you can select the children you want like `$('#parentId tr td input')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't reuse your id : only one element can have a given one.

Here, you shouldn't even use the same name but a class.

Then change

```
$("#layer_pk").each(function(idx, elem) {
          checks.push($(elem).val());
});
```

to

```
$(".layer_pk").each(function(idx, elem) {
          checks.push($(elem).val());
});
```

or, in a simpler way :

```
$(".layer_pk").each(function() {
          checks.push(this.value);
});
```

or

```
var checks = $('.layer_pk').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
```

Comment: var checks = $('.layer_pk').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();

Answer (score 1):

Just to reiterate:  `$("#layer_pk").length` equals 1, no matter how many elements you have on the page with that same id.  If you use an id selector, jQuery only sees the first element with that id.  So keep your id's unique.